# Grub installation keeps failing 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

i am having a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a new HP laptop. I tried several distributions before ubuntu like manjaro,mint and opensuse and i only managed to boot live ubuntu,mint and opensuse using the flag `acpi=off`, manjaro would not boot no matter what i tried. I should mention here that i have uefi with gpt and i have disabled secure boot and disabled legacy mode.

Upon installing mint,ubuntu and opensuse only opensuse did manage to install the grub2 properly. When ubuntu or mint attempt an install on grub2 it failed giving error `grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/`

i searched for this error and attempted the solutions suggested but i did not manage to get it to work. Please note that every time i tried something i did a clean install over and over.

i finally tried the boot-repair tool which also creates a pastebin file which is this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/snsKNVnCTq/

please let me know if you have something to suggest cause i am out of ideas and i do not understand why i do have to use the `acpi=off` flag or why the grub keeps failing to install of why manjaro failed to even boot from live usb.

Comment: Some with new systems still need UEFI update from vendor. And if SSD may need firmware update to SSD. You used the LVM -  Advanced Volume management. That is more used by servers but is required if you want full drive encryption. Generally more for advanced users as you cannot use standard tools to maintain it, but must use LVM tools.

Answer (score 0):

acpi=off is turning off your acpi while ubuntu is booting, and if you need it to boot Ubuntu it suggests that your acpi is not compatible with this version of Ubuntu. You can add this permanently to the grub installer after your installation is complete if it did not get added automatically.

As for the grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ issue, from what I found with a quick search, your installation is missing some dependencies.

The resolution suggested is that you have your system connected to the internet during the install and that you enable the

```
download updates during the installation
```

in the prepare stage of the installer. If you still have problems after this, then you should check in the system log for further details which you can post on here.